# htaccess is not redirecting in server

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, .htaccess

I'm having problem with a .htaccess file removing `request.php` from URL. My htaccess file is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # deal with php5-cgi first
    <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ request.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_fcgid.c>
        # for normal Apache installations
        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ request.php/$1 [L]
        </IfModule>
        # for Apache FGCI installations
        <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ request.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

The htaccess file (and all files) is located at localhost/firstDirectory/secondDirectory/

When I try to access to request.php from

```
http://localhost/firstDirectory/secondDirectory/some/value
```

works fine, but when I try from

```
http://mydomain.com/theapp/some/value
```

it doesn't works. In this case htaccess file is located at /var/www/theapp and theapp is a symbolic link to /mnt/data/theapp

Why at local server works but not in the remote server? htaccess file must be placed at another location? like document root for example?

Comment: Are there any *other* differences between these servers besides the file path?  Particularly in the rest of the Apache configuration.  You could be missing mod_rewrite or not have a `RewriteEngine on` clause or not have AllowOverride switched on or something else entirely.  Do a diff on each of the files to find the difference and then add it to your question.